# How to insert data without duplicates in Mongodb using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have two tables called `tbl1` and `tbl2` , `tbl1` is the primary table and it will get updated by some other team every 5 minutes, I have to take data from `tbl1` and need to insert in `tbl2` without any duplicates using Java, can someone tell me how to deal with this?.

Comment: How often do you need to do this? Wouldn't it be easier to let the other team write directly to one table rather than trying to reconcile the data between two tables periodically? 
Can you provide a sample of what the tables look like?

Comment: Would you also be inserting data into tbl2?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you'll also be inserting into `tbl2`, you could simply set up a replica set where `tbl1` is the primary and `tbl2` is secondary.

See [Mongo replication docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/)